# ASP.NET Gridview Loading Slower with more data bindings

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2008 and populating my gridview with sqldatasoure .And inside itemtemplate of gridview there are some dropdownlist which are again being binded with sqldatasource and on rowdatabound event am assigning selected values for these dropdownlist. There are nearly 2000+ records which makes grid to load very slower. Any ideas for optimizing this.

```
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
  <asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
      AutoGenerateColumns="False" onrowdatabound="Gridview1_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="Dropdownlist1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="empid" DataValueField="empname">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("empid") %>' />
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="Dropdownlist2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="desgid" DataValueField="desgname">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField2" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("desgid") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$     ConnectionStrings:dbconn %>'
    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="SP_Fetch_Grid">    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbconn %>'
    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="SP_Fetch_DDL1"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbconn %>'
    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="SP_Fetch_DDL2"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
</form>

protected void Gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        HiddenField hf1 = (HiddenField)e.Row.FindControl("HiddenField1");
        HiddenField hf2 = (HiddenField)e.Row.FindControl("HiddenField2");
        DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1");
        DropDownList ddl2 = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList2");
        ddl1.SelectedValue = hf1.Value;
        ddl2.SelectedValue = hf2.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend to design the UI in a different way. A ddl with +2000 records is not the best practice in terms of usability.

Comment: @aleafonso I think the OP means 2000 records in the GridView.

Comment: there is a need to to select values from list for each row. I think i cant find other alternate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull the dropdown list set once into memory, and bind against that. That will save you 2000+ server round trips.

Edit - Create a small class, something like this:

```
public static class DropDownListCache
{
    private static Func<DataTable> m_getDataFunc = 
            () => AccessYourDAL.GetYourDropdownListTableData1();
    private static Func<DataTable> m_getDataFunc = 
            () => AccessYourDAL.GetYourDropdownListTableData2();

    private static Lazy<DataTable> DropDown1 = 
            new Lazy<TDataType>(m_getDataFunc1,true);
    private static Lazy<DataTable> DropDown2 = 
            new Lazy<TDataType>(m_getDataFunc2,true);

    public static DataTable GetDropDownList1()
    {
        return DropDown1;
    }

    public static DataTable GetDropDownList2()
    {
        return DropDown2;
    }
}
```

Then replace `SqlDataSource2` and `SqlDataSource3` with Object Data Source objects, that point to the two methods on the cache object.

You need to write the code for `AccessYourDAL.GetYourDropdownListTableData1();` and `AccessYourDAL.GetYourDropdownListTableData2();`

Those are just placeholders.  This should make sure that you only pay 2 round trips for the entire grid, rather then 2 per row.

1+n*2 database calls becomes 1+2 database calls.

Comment: yes i tried that too i binded those sqldatasource to one dropdownlist and during onrowdatabound event i find a panel inside itemtemplate added inside it, but it is not showing during runtime.

Comment: Use an Object Data Source that points to a method that returns a copy of the cached dropdown list result.

Comment: cached dropdown list? Wat do u meant?

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't display 2000 rows of **anything** at a time.
2. Set up [paging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5aw1xfh3.aspx) on your `GridView`.
3. If the first two items didn't help, consider switching to a [`Repeater`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) control instead.
4. Verify that your SQL query returns your data in a reasonable time frame (2-3 seconds).

Comment: Hi Thanks, 4. SQL Query displays records in seconds. 2. I am using Clientside filter, so when paging used, it is only filtering those paged rows. 1. I never used repeater control, i google it, if u have any working code pls post here.

Comment: @M.Bharnidharan, I edited my answer to include a link to the MSDN help article on the `Repeater` control -- there's an example of it at the bottom of the page. You should know that it is **very** basic, and doesn't include a lot of the features (like built-in paging) that the `GridView` control does. I'd suggest, based on your comment here, that you might also consider using a server-side filter if that's at all possible. You could also look into some jQuery/JavaScript grid options, but unfortunately I can't make any recommendations there.

Comment: thanks, i started with server side filter by adding filter expression to sqldatasoure and ended with more difficulties like appending filter expressions when selectcommand is a stored procedure, and when using controlparameters for filter, i cant able to place my controls inside gridview and so went to jquery filtering.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative could be optimizing the sql query by adding an index on the column that is being used to populate the DropDownList.